# kvo style : why cannot the value be updated with pointers?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, key-value-observing

i was reading a tutorial about `KVO`, the example shows that the value is not updated when we don't use KVO style, so i was wondering: why , if the object is passed by "reference" (with `id` or `Position*`) , and so if we use a pointer to "anObject", won't the value (from the object) be updated?

so here's the code : in "main" :

```
// Create initial position
Position* pos = [[Position alloc] init];
pos.latitude = 45.0;
pos.longitude = 12.0;
pos.altitude = 30.0;

// Create a basic tracker
ValueTracker * tracker = [ValueTracker createValueTrackerForKey:@"latitude" onObject:pos];

// Dump initial state
NSLog(@"Tracker (1): %@", tracker);

pos.latitude += 5.0;
pos.longitude += 5.0;
pos.altitude += 10.0;

NSLog(@"Tracker (2): %@", tracker); //the values are not updated
```

the object :

```
@interface Position : NSObject {

    float latitude;
    float longitude;
    float altitude;
}

@property(assign, readwrite) float latitude;
@property(assign, readwrite) float longitude;
@property(assign, readwrite) float altitude;
```

and the function : here, `anObject` is a pointer to `Position`, why can't the value be updated using the pointer?

```
+ (ValueTracker *) createValueTrackerForKey: (NSString *) aKey 
                                 onObject: (id) anObject
{
    ValueTracker * tracker = [[ValueTracker alloc] init];

    tracker.valueKey = aKey;
    tracker.source = anObject;
    tracker.value = [anObject valueForKey: tracker.valueKey];

    return tracker;
}
```

---

edit: here's when we use the kvo system :

```
[tracker enableObserving];
```

and in the ValueTracker class :

```
- (void) enableObserving
{
    if ( nil != source ) {
        /* We specify in options that we want to get both old and new value
         for the property.
         */
        [source addObserver: self 
                 forKeyPath: valueKey 
                    options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |
                             NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
                    context: NULL];
    }
}
```

---

edit n°2 :

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath: (NSString *) keyPath 
                       ofObject: (id) object 
                         change: (NSDictionary *) change 
                        context: (void *) context
{
    NSLog(@"Value %@ changed! Here is the changeset: %@", keyPath, change);
    //NSLog(@"Dump on observation: %@", [self description]);
    value = [change valueForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
}
```

Comment: What are you actually expecting to happen in that code? From what you have provided I would guess that the tracker object would have the same value for `latitude` both times it is printed. You mention KVO but you are not using it in this code...

Comment: @Paul.s : yeah, i edited my post, but my question is about "why" the pointer is not just enough the change the value? it is, actually the same value, but `anObject` is a pointer, so i'm a bit confused, i thought because we're using a pointer, the value would be able to be updated wherever in the code.

Comment: @Paul you also need to show `observeValueForKeyPath:` implementation

Comment: @hamstergene : okay, i edited my post, but do you know what i mean? i'm wondering, as a general rule, why the pointer is not enough to update the variable?

Comment: @Paul Here, the reason why `observeValueForKeyPath:` doesn't fire may be that `source` is `nil` at the time when `enableObserving` is called, or you have forgot to make this call completely.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to synthesize your iVars?

```
@implementation Position

@synthesize latitude, longitude, altitude;

...

@end
```

Comment: thanks moosgummi for your answer, no actually i got the synthesize (i did not copied and paste the whole object here), but i was more wondering about, as a general rule, why the pointer is not enough to update the variable?